# Import package in project in gingerbread source code

Tags: android

I am customizing the native Contact application in Gingerbread.
I want to call a class from native Mms Application,
I have imported the class,

> > import com.android.mms.ui.*;

But I am getting error,

> > could not find the package com.android.mms.ui

can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import MMS application's classes in another APK. The classes have to be in framework code.

Comment: thanx for the reply, but then how packeges of PHONE App is imported in Contact App?

Comment: can you post which package is imported?

Comment: In Contact,
>>com.android.contacts.TwelveKeyDialer.java

These packages are imported
 
>>import com.android.phone.CallLogAsync;
>>import com.android.phone.HapticFeedback;

Comment: if you see the make file of phone app , 3 files including above are built in a separate module com.android.phone.common . This module is inturn added in your Contacts Android.mk under LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES. Thats why contacts is able to build. Technically that is not part of the apk. It would have created a jar file

Comment: Thanks nandeesh, I have updated the Android.mk file of contact and mms, as the phone does.!
Now I solved the error "Package could not find", mms package is imported in contact, but there are so many error from mms packages, compiler cannot find the other packages of mms app.

Comment: Importing Ui elements in such a way is quite difficult. Those files in contacts app just have helper functions. You will have to create a jar file like contacts app does and then import that jar file instead of importing whole apk